# Database synchronization 2 times a day -MariaDB

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, mysqldump, data-synchronization

I have 2 different servers. The first one is server1 and the other is server2. On servers, one works for websites (server1) and the other for mobile applications (server2) for security purposes. I want to add changes (insert, delete, update) to the database used on the websites to the database that the mobile application uses. I want to do this every afternoon and evening.

I've looked at other topics on this topic, but I couldn't find them.

I don't want to write the IP address of the other server (server2) to the server (server1) used by the websites (for security). That's why I can't replicate. So server2 will connect to server1 twice a day and update different data.

There can be close to 1 million records per day. I don't know if I can do it with Mysqldumps. insert and deleting all tables may be a problem.

Do you have any suggestions? How do I synchronize a database?

Comment: A Slave connects to a Master, not the other way around.

Comment: Do both servers receive writes from the clients? (I.e. from users on mobile phones and browsers.) If so, do you have thoughts on how you will you handle or avoid collisions? Also, still assuming both servers receive writes from clients, if you only ever write from server1 to server2, then server1 will become increasingly out of synch with the full dataset. Is that really what you want?